# How access multiple column values in a numpy structured array in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to numpy and still learning it.
I created a structured array as below:

```
name = ['Alice', 'Beth', 'Cathy', 'Dorothy']
studentid = [1,2,3,4]
score = [85.4, 90.4, 87.66, 78.9]
student_data = np.zeros(4, dtype={'names':('name', 'studentId', 'score'), 
                         'formats':('U10', 'i4', 'f8')})
student_data['name'] = name
student_data['studentId'] = studentid
student_data['score']=score
```

Inorder to get the names of people who have scores greater than 85, I wrote this:

```
student_data[student_data['score'] > 85]['name']
```

But if I try to retrieve another column along with 'name', I am getting an error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

For example, I tried the below ways:

```
student_data[student_data['score'] < 90]['name','studentid']
student_data[student_data['score'] < 90]['name']['studentid']
```

Both of them result in the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-189-7ad7c151f0e3> in <module>
----> 1 student_data[student_data['score'] < 90]['name']['studentid']

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here & how can I retrieve multiple columns on conditional basis ?

Comment: The relevant docs: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-multiple-fields.  "the index is a list of field names."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access multiple fields from a structured numpy.array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271828/how-to-access-multiple-fields-from-a-structured-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can access with array of columns:

```
student_data[student_data['score'] < 90][['name','studentid']]
```

Output:

```
array([('Alice', 1), ('Cathy', 3), ('Dorothy', 4)],
      dtype={'names':['name','studentId'], 'formats':['<U10','<i4'], 'offsets':[0,40], 'itemsize':52})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`

```
print(student_data[np.where(student_data['score'] < 90)][['name', 'studentId']])

[('Alice', 1) ('Cathy', 3) ('Dorothy', 4)]
```